# Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "stage-0" relative to directory

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I am getting the following error but only when I try to use the following dependency, otherwise it works fine.

Error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "stage-0" relative to directory
```

Import causing the issue

`import {ActionDone} from "material-ui"`

It is part of the react-material-icons npm package. If I remove that import and uses of it everything works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

You only need to install babel-preset-stage-0:

Command for this:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0`

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the stage 0 preset.

Refer to this article: 
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall babel using command

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```